# Matplotlib wont get installed when building docker container

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib

Trying to build a docker container with a python script. It breaks when trying to install matplotlib.  At the required dependencies, it says `png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not be found.]`, however, I can't find a package named `libpng` anywhere for python. This is the error msg:

```
Collecting matplotlib==2.2.2
  Downloading matplotlib-2.2.2.tar.gz (37.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9zxcndql/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9zxcndql/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-9zxcndql/matplotlib/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9zxcndql/matplotlib/
    Complete output (55 lines):
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

 BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.2]
                    python: yes [3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 02:15:29)  [GCC
                            6.4.0]]
                  platform: yes [linux]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
      install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                        be found.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
```

Comment: It's C library headers, not a Python library, and you need to `RUN apt-get install ...` to make that available.

Comment: that means putting "RUN apt-get install matplotlib" into my dockerfile? Because that causes the error:

Step 5/12 : RUN apt-get install matplotlib
 ---> Running in 630b330b3996
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found